# Bootstrap, show data-toggle="tab" in the url

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="clearfix">
<ul class="section-categories">
<li><a href="#all_games" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">a</a></li>
<li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">b</a></li>
<li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">c</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

can the tabs be displayed in the url? so i can do this:

```
<li><a href="index.php?Like=#a" data-toggle="tab">a</a></li>
$tab_like = $_GET['Like'];
$tab_content::find_by_first_letter($tab_like);
```

Now bootsrap prevents it from showing it in the url, followed several guide's, some guide's i followed displayed it in the url, but still the $_GET variable couldn't get it out of it :(
i have 0 experience in javascript so i hope you can explain it simple for me
i also hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few characters which you're not allowed to use in URL parameters because they have a special meaning in the URL. the `#` character is one of them. What you need to do is encode the value of the parameter. So this should work:

```
<?php

echo '<li><a href="index.php?Like='.urlencode('#a')." data-toggle="tab">a</a></li>';

?>
```

or any variant hereof.

Comment: yeah i just typed this quickly to give you guys the idea of what i'm going to do, the biggest problem is that it doesn't show up in the url, so i can't do $_GET on it

Comment: Are you serious? So, give us the code without quickly typed bugs.

Comment: Most is copied man... my question is how i show the tabs in to the url

Comment: If you think your code is correct, then read my answer again, and think: "Could this really be the cause of my problem?". And then think that again.

Comment: KIKO i already tried your solution, but it encode's the # so the tab doesn't work anymore...